# What does 'to' mean in "One of my favorite updates has been to the entryway and stair area of the house."?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the meaning of 'to' in the sentence?

> One of my favorite updates has been ***to*** the entryway and stair area of the house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence says that:

- there are potentially several updates
- one of them is about / was applied to the [entryway and stair area of the house]
- that single update is one of the speaker's favorites

If you would omit the "to", the meaning would change: it would mean that the favorite update *is* the [entryway and stair area of the house] as a whole (not just something that was done to it).